# How can show content in another class?

Tags: html, css

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
<style>
.left {
background-color:pink;
    min-width: 10%;
    max-width: 10px;
    min-height: 700px;
    max-height: 90%; 
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-left: 15px;
    margin-right: 25px;
    position: fixed;
}
.right {
  min-height: 800px;
  max-height: 80%;   
  min-width: 76%;   
  max-width: 980px;
  float: right;
  margin-right: 30px;
  margin-left: 30px;
  position: relative;
} 
.drp {display:none; background-color:grey; width:100px; height:100px;}
.navbar:hover .drp {display:block;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="main">
  <div class="left">
    <div class="navbar">
        <button>hover</button>
        <div class="drp">
        <ul>
        <li>link 1</li>
        <li> link2 </li>
        <li> link 3 </li>
        <li> link 4 </li>
        </ul>
        <div>
    </div>
  </div >
  <div class="right">
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

when hover on div "navbar" it's shows the content but it is not showing whole content . It's hidden inside parent class because size of parent class is smaller than content.

So how can i display that content in div "right" ?

Answer (score 0):

Please check below solution. It will solve your css problem.
`max-width` and `width` should match, as `overflow` is hidden.

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Page Title</title>
  <style>
    .left {
      background-color: pink;
      width: 50%;
      min-width: 10%;
      height: 100px;
      min-height: 700px;
      float: left;
      overflow: hidden;
      margin-left: 15px;
      margin-right: 25px;
      position: fixed;
    }
    
    .right {
      min-height: 800px;
      max-height: 80%;
      min-width: 76%;
      max-width: 980px;
      float: right;
      margin-right: 30px;
      margin-left: 30px;
      position: relative;
    }
    
    .drp {
      display: none;
      background-color: grey;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
    }
    
    .navbar:hover .drp {
      display: block;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="main">
    <div class="left">
      <div class="navbar">
        <button>hover</button>
        <div class="drp">
          <ul>
            <li>link 1</li>
            <li> link2 </li>
            <li> link 3 </li>
            <li> link 4</li>
          </ul>
          <div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="right">
        </div>
      </div>

</body>

</html>
```

I hope this is what you are looking for.

Comment: I don't want to change size of class. I need that much size only.

Comment: You have assigned `overflow:hidden `, hence your `.drp` is not able to show all its content. Plus `max-width` is very less. I will update my answer again. Check that.